# Detecting a ListView click in a custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform

I have a created a ListView with a custom layout showing the users saved on Parse.com
This is the code for the custom adapter I have created

```
public class StatusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    protected Context mContext;
    protected List mStatus;

    public StatusAdapter(Context context, List status) {
        super(context, R.layout.usertem, status);
        mContext = context;
        mStatus = status;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.usertem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.usernameHomepage = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.userName);
            holder.statusHomepage = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
            holder.proPic = (ParseImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.medopic);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ParseUser statusObject = (ParseUser) mStatus.get(position);

        // title
        String username = statusObject.getString("name");
        holder.usernameHomepage.setText(username);

        // content
        String status = statusObject.getEmail();
        holder.statusHomepage.setText(status);
        ParseFile picc = statusObject.getParseFile("profile_picture");
        holder.proPic.setParseFile(picc);
        holder.proPic.loadInBackground();

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView usernameHomepage;
        TextView statusHomepage;
        ParseImageView proPic;

    }
}
```

But the problem I have is that I want to listen to list item clicks where my activity extends simple activity not List Activity this is my activity

```
public class UsersList extends Activity {
private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;
ListView listhope;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_list);
    listhope = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userlistlist);
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("_User");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                mUsers = list;

                StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(listhope.getContext(), mUsers);
                listhope.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {

            }

        }
    });

}
[...]
```

Please help fast

Comment: implements OnItemClick in your adapter and add `listHope.setOnItemClickListener(adapter)` in your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onCreate write

```
listhope.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


  //position is the row on which the user has clicked


     ParseUser parseUser=mUsers.get(position);
      //now you have the objext parseUser and this objects is what you needed.


        }


    });
```

Comment: but how can I use this to get data from the parse database and actually what is the position

Comment: @MohamedSherifNoureldin position is basically the row on which you have clicked in listview.